# Updating in Tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to update one table from one database to another table on another database. This will need to be run once a day. Both tables are the same structure.

One database is called `pvc_rds` and the other is called `kiosk`. The table is `REC_Materials`. There is a column called `sid` that is unique. Both these live on the same SQL Server 2008.

I am new to this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what the exact question is. Please be more specific and provide the schema of the two tables.

Comment: [UPDATE .. JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) or [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) are two likely candidates ..

Answer (score 0):

Use (at least) a three-part [identifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx).

> The complete name of an object is made up of four identifiers: the server name, database name, schema name, and object name. They appear in the following format:
>
> server_name.[database_name].[schema_name].object_name

In your case, this would simply translate to (assuming the dbo schema for your tables) :

```
UPDATE pvc_rds.dbo.REC_Materials
FROM pvc_rds.dbo.REC_Materials
INNER JOIN kiosk.dbo.REC_Materials
ON pvc_rds.dbo.REC_Materials.sid = kiosk.dbo.REC_Materials.sid
```

in order to synchronise existing records present in both databases. You can expand on this to remove records that shouldn't be there anymore and add any new records. You can save that process into a [job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx), and make it run everyday by [scheduling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx) it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to create a scheduled job, which contains a step that queries the source server (source database) and insert into the target database. However, you must use the complete name of the object, as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx

The more complicated answer depends on your overall goal.  Is the source database, a transaction database and the target database the reporting database?  In which case, is your goal to replicate the data using transaction or merge replication?